# dropdown menu display effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown button that display 2 options when clicked I want the option to display like fading in and out when the dropdown is clicked.

HTML

```
<select name="lang_choice" id="lang_choice">
    <option value="da" selected="selected">Dansk</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>

</select>
```

CSS

```
select
{
    background: #E6E0D0;
    color: #694a31;
    width: 100px;
}
```

i tried to add this to my css but nothing happens also tried the opacity 0 > 1 when display but it doesn't affect the menu.

```
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
```

sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dvcam8f/)

Comment: You can use the plugin [Animation Drop drown](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/dropdown)

Comment: the effects are good but I need is just a simple fade in and out to match with my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try jQuery animation, but it seems that `opacity` only affects the option text and not the block where it is stored.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dvcam8f/5/

new jsfiddle with better animation: http://jsfiddle.net/2dvcam8f/9/

If you want smooth drop downs you should use plugins, for example the one @Rushee posted.

Comment: your sample animation doesnt work for me in chrome. but working in firefox.

Comment: I will later check when I got home, I might missed something. It should work on Chrome too.